# Why \ell produce a character like grave in PDF?

Tags: math-mode, characters

```
\`{}$\ell$
\bye
```

produces a PDF, then I search ` in it, finding two, why?
[image]

Comment: I **don't** see that behaviour with either Preview.app or Skim.app on OS X, so I guess it's a feature of what ever viewer you are using.

Comment: Can you specify what TeX distribution you're using?

Comment: Try adding `\input glyphtounicode` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because `'` and `\ell` have the same encoding, who are just in different fonts.

The following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\teni=cmmi10

\begin{document}
    \char'140\relax\char"60

    \teni\char'140\relax\char"60
\end{document}
```

will produce:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Then searching ' will hit both characters in Adobe Acorbat (not ` though, so it might have something to do with the OS or the viewer).

Comment: My OS is Ubuntu, the viewer is Evince.